# What is the data-dojo-props used to specify text alignment = right?

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I have been trying the documentation of dijit textbox, but there seem to be no proper documentation on how to do text-align: right css style settings.

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="testing testing"
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
    data-dojo-props="trim:true, propercase:true" id="firstname" />
```

If I add the "align: right" the parse fails. I also tried via CSS but the text-align seem to not be reflected.

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="testing testing"
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
    data-dojo-props="trim:true, propercase:true, align: right" id="firstname" />
```

I also tried text align via css style but it does not parse well.

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="testing testing"
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
    data-dojo-props="style: { width: '150px'; text-align: right}" id="firstname" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible to set text alignments using `data-dojo-props` attribute. However you can solve your problem using `CSS` selectors:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="testing testing"
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
    data-dojo-props="trim:true, propercase:true, align: right" id="firstname" />
```

**CSS (examples):**

```
input[name="firstname"] {
 text-align: right;   
}
```

or

```
#firstname {
 text-align: right;   
}
```

another elegant approach would be, to create an attribute selector querying the `align: right` value of your `data-dojo-props` attribute. With this selector you can reach all of your input items once.

```
input[data-dojo-props*="align: right"] {
 text-align: right;   
}
```

Here you can find an [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddev/Lqjhnase/) example.

---

### UPDATE:

I have done some further investigations and I came to the conclusion that it is a syntax problem why the dojo parsing fails.

The following piece of code works without parsing errors:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="testing testing"
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
    data-dojo-props="trim:true, propercase:true, style:'text-align: right'" id="firstname" />
```

but the result is not as expected:

```
    <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox"
 id="widget_firstname" role="presentation" widgetid="firstname" style="text-
align: right;"><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer">
<input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" data-dojo-attach-
point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" name="firstname" type="text" 
tabindex="0" id="firstname" value="Testing Testing"></div></div>
```

because the styling will applied to the wrapper div.

I my opinion the best way to handle your requirements is to work only with CSS stylings without using the data-dojo-props attribute.

Comment: as stated in the question, when I tried to add the data-dojo-props= align:right in the HTML declaration, the dojo stopped parsing. succeeding dojo declarative to that point was not converted to dojo control just normal HTML input control. Which means the parser has an error.

Answer (score 1):

Dojo supports right aligned text inputs natively through bi-directional text support https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/quickstart/internationalization/bi-directional-text.html

This is intended to reverse the text direction of a portion or the entire page (including inputs) by setting the `dir` tag on an element:

```
<body dir="rtl">
    <!-- Widgets Here -->
</body>
```

However, that probably isn't what you want. Try this CSS:

```
.dijitInputContainer .dijitInputInner {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: yes, the right align text i meant was for numerical values inside a textbox not the text direction.